# ERROR while Generate a Dictonary with list has default value and append values to it

Tags: python

In python Dictionary we can check if key exists and assign a default like '0' and can do any add, subtraction like below

```
d['a'] = d.get('a',0) + 1
```

Here i want to have empty list as default value and append value
One line implementation is giving error saying None type don't have append()

```
d['a'] = d.get('a',[]).append(1)
```

expecting `d{'a':[1]}`

with below implementation in can achieve above result

```
d['a'] = d.get('a',[])
d['a'].append(1)
```

Why is this happening?

Why one line implementation is error while the 2nd implementation not?

Comment: `append` modifies a list inplace and returns `None`. You can use `d['a'] = d.get('a',[]) + [1]` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what does `d.get('a',[]).append(1)` return?

**`None`**

so you assign `None` to `d['a']`

`list.append()` does an in place modification of the list.

Use `defaultdict`

```py
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
d['a'].append(1)
```

Comment: Oh now I get it Thanks